# I want to display a circular progress indicator using jquery in asp.net when textbox textchange event occurs

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I want to display a circular progress indicator using jquery in asp.net when textbox textchange event occurs. When user enters some value in a textbox and textchange event occurs or when user loses the focus on that textbox, system checks values in databases. I want to give user a progress indicator type when query is in progress.

How can I accomplish this with jquery?

Code here:

```
 $("#Txturl").blur(function() { 
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/Getvalue",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,


        success: function(msg) {                  
            ///to to do here? i ve no idea;                    
        }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Is this an ajax application? Do you want to send a request to update the database when focus is lost on the textbox or do you want to load a predefined list of values at page load?

Comment: I want to check value in database against value entered in textbox.(I am not showing it)I  already written functions for value matching are . I am just concerned with Jquery , progress indicator and when value are matched how to stop or hide indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward. You would start by creating the animated GIF for your indicator (or download a freely available one) and add it to your site. Then in your Javascript, you would add something closely resembling the following:

```
$('#yourTextBox').change(
    function(){
        $("#yourProgressImg").show(); 
        $.ajax({
            type : "get",
            url : <your request uri>,
            success: <what to do if it comes back happy>
            fail: <what to do if it fails>
            complete: function(){ $("#yourProgressImg").hide(); }
        });
     }
);
```

The complete functionality of the `$.ajax()` function is here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: thanks. I will try it.actually i am new to jquery and wants to moving away from update panel.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how every other site does it, but I would show an animated GIF on the textchange event and hide it in the AJAX success (or failure) function.

Have a hidden div with your animated GIF.

```
<style>.hidden { display: none; }</style>
<div class="hidden"><img src="spinner.gif" /></div>
```

Then show it on change and hide it in the success or error callback.

```
$('#mytextbox').change(function(){
    $('#divwithGIF').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Default.aspx/Getvalue',
        data: '{}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        complete: function(msg){
            $('#divwithGIF').hide();
        };
    });
});
```

Repeat for the blur() event.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer on this one: [jquery submit and loading gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095740/jquery-submit-and-loading-gif/3095817#3095817) for an example of how you can construct a global (on the page) event monitor for ajax to display an animated gif as you describe.  You can customize this as you wish for your events.